# How do I create a seamless transition between input forms?

Tags: css

I have a simple registration form that I'm building, I've added code to make the height of the input fields change when clicked.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png"/>
    <h2>Register Your Device</h2>

    <form id="preload">
        <fieldset>
            <label>SERIAL NUMBER<br>
                <input type="text" name="registrationid">
            </label><br>

            <label>USERNAME<br>
                <input type="text" name="username">
            </label><br>

            <label>PASSWORD<br>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <input class="button" type="button" name="register" value="REGISTER">
        </fieldset>

    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for that:

```
input {
    font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
    outline:none;
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px 10px;
    margin:10px 0 20px 0;

width:100%;
    max-width: 290px;
    height:15px;
    transition:0.3s;
}

input:focus {
    height:30px;
    color:#3ea9f5;
    border:1px solid #3ea9f5;
}
```

Now my problem is that with this is that it makes the forms fade in on load as well, when I only want the forms to transition in height when clicked.

I used this little method:

```
.preload * {
    transition:none;
}
```

and it gets rid of the unwanted fade in transtion, but when I click a different form, the height instantly jumps back to the original height without a transition to the original height.

How would I fix this? Hopefully I worded this well enough for an answer.

Comment: I'm assuming the `.fade` class is fading something in on page load, no? If so, we need that CSS, too. Because your code isn't fading anything in on load currently. We need a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: the .fade class was my poor attempt to fix it. I edited that out of the code.

Comment: Then what causes things to fade in? And have you tried changing the `transition` line on the `input` to `transition: height 0.3s;`?

Comment: That just solved my problem! Wow, thanks.

Comment: Ah sweet. I submitted that as an answer about 20 minutes ago, but deleted it since I wasn't sure. Want me to undelete and you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transition property for `input` doesn't specify a property to animate, so it's defaulting to selecting all properties to apply the transition.

Try this:

```
input {
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  transition: height 0.3s ease, border-color 0.3s ease;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: #3ea9f5;
}
```

That targets only specific properties of the selector to transition. Using `ease` also smooths out the transition a little more, too. Also, don't forget to include browser fallbacks for `transition`.